# Updating the value in a dictionary at the proper index

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary which has a key `product_quantity`. Now `product_quantity` has a value of '1'. But later on `product_quantity` gets a different value from a picker view and at that time I want the value of `product_quantity` in the dictionary to be updated. In other words I want to update the values in dictionary. But how that can be achieved that I'm not able to figure out.

Something like this is so far done..Here the `index` that I have given is just initialized as `var index = Int()` and it always has a value of 0. So it doesn't work.

Hope somebody can help...

```
self.appDelegate.myDictionary["product_quantity"] = cell.qtyPickerField.text!

self.appDelegate.arrayOfDictionary[index] = self.appDelegate.myDictionary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed like so...

The index of the tableviewcell can be found like this...

```
 let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
  if let index1 = indexPath {            

    }
```

Then a common int variable was declared and the value of `index1` at `0` was assigned to that variable and that variable in turn was passed to my array of dictionary like so...

```
 let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
      if let index1 = indexPath {            
         self.theValueOfIndex = index1[0]
    }
```

Then,

```
myDictionary["product_quantity"] = cell.qtyPickerField.text!


arrayOfDictionary[self.theValueOfIndex] = myDictionary
```

This updated the value at the correct index.

Comment: `index1[0]` compiles but consider that it's the equivalent to `indexPath.section` rather than `indexPath.row`. It's highly recommended to use the *human readable* members `row` and `section` anyway.

Comment: Ok @vadian. Thanks...but hope things the way they are now won't give any issues in giving the desired result...

Comment: If you intend to use the `section` everything’s fine.

Comment: you mean section instead of `index1[0]`..?

Comment: Yes, I mean to use `row` and `section` rather than the index to avoid confusion and increase the readability.

Comment: oh..ok @vadian Thanks...:) Also, let me deviate a bit from the normal practice & ask a help.…it seems to be simple …maybe I missed something somewhere..I had put up a concern some time ago..but couldn’t yet get an answer..maybe you can put in some help..just a request in case u don’t mind…:)  pardon if it annoyed...:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432449/adding-specific-elements-in-an-array

Comment: Unfortunalely you don't provide sufficient code in you question(s) to comprehend the actual workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `struct` to hold the data you want.

```
struct Product {
    var quantity: Int
}
```

Then create an object of this struct.

```
var product = Product(quantity: 0)
```

Then you just need to update the quantity variable at some point later in the program.

```
product.quantity = 10
```

Update:
Just saw your edit.

```
struct Product {
    var quantity: Int
}

struct MyData {
    var product: Product
    mutating func updateProduct(quantity: Int) {
        product.quantity = quantity
    }
}


var product = Product(quantity: 0)
var myData = MyData(product: product)
print(myData.product.quantity)

// call the updateProduct method to update the quantity.
myData.updateProduct(quantity: 20)
print(myData.product.quantity)
```

Comment: but will this result in my dictionary values getting updated..? at the correct index...?

Comment: ok @MjZac. Here as I can see you have updated the quantity from 0 to 20. But my updated value has to go to the correct index of my dictionary. How can that be done..?

Comment: @bvt With `MyData` struct you wont be needing an array to keep track of the values. You have just an instance of the struct to play with. I take you have other dictionaries too. ( and those are added to the array !? ) If you refactor the code to use structs and a wrapper struct to hold the values, you wont need to deal with indices.

Comment: Actually I need the `product_quantity ` in a dictionary because in my API call the dictionary as a whole goes as a parameter...

Comment: You can always construct the dictionary from the structure object right before api call.